# An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property DoStuff(int, int)'

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int number1,number2;
            number1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            number2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("the sum of numbers are " +" "+ (number1 + number2));
            Console.ReadKey();
            DoStuff(number1,number2);
        }

        public int DoStuff(int num1,int num2)
        {
            int result = num1 + num2;
            return result;
        }

    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You are not allowed to call a non-static method inside a static method. If you want to invoke then you need a object reference. This is because the static methods cannot be instantiate. So the method `DoStuff` should be static, hence its signature may looks like this:

```
public static int DoStuff(int num1,int num2)
{
    int result = num1 + num2;
    return result;
}
```

I have one more suggestion for you to improve your code; it is nothing but use [`int.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) instead for simple `.Parse`. Which helps you to handle FormatException too. So the complete code will looks like:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int number1, number2;
        if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out number1) && int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out number2))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("the sum of numbers are :{0}", DoStuff(number1, number2));
        }
        else
            Console.ReadKey();
    }
    public static int DoStuff(int num1, int num2)
    {
        int result = num1 + num2;
        return result;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

From a static function you can call only static functions.
So change your `DoStuff` function to be static:

```
public static int DoStuff(int num1,int num2)
{
    int result = num1 + num2;
    return result;
}
```

For more info: [Static classes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx)

A non-static member belongs to an instance. It's meaningless without somehow resolving which instance of a class you are talking about. In a static context, you don't have an instance, that's why you can't access a non-static member without explicitly mentioning an object reference.

In fact, you **can** access a non-static member in a static context by specifying the object reference explicitly:

```
class HelloWorld {
   int i;
   public HelloWorld(int i) { this.i = i; }
   public static void Print(HelloWorld instance) {
      Console.WriteLine(instance.i);
   }
}

var test = new HelloWorld(1);
var test2 = new HelloWorld(2);
HelloWorld.Print(test);
```

Without explicitly referring to the instance in the Print method, how would it know it should print 1 and not 2?

Answer (score 0):

You are using DoStuff as a static method.

You should do the following:

```
...
Console.ReadKey();
var program = new Program();
program.DoStuff(number1, number2);
...
```

So create an instance of your class and call the method upon it.

If you do want to use the method in a static way, you should declare it statically:

```
public static int DoStuff(int num1,int num2)
{
    int result = num1 + num2;
    return result;
}
```

See the "static" keyword after "public".

Answer (score 0):

From C# Specifications:

> 1.6.6.3 Static and instance methods
>
> A method declared with a static modifier is a static method. A static method does not operate on a
> specific instance and can only directly access static members. A
> method declared without a static modifier is an instance method. An
> instance method operates on a specific instance and can access both
> static and instance members. The instance on which an instance method
> was invoked can be explicitly accessed as this. It is an error to
> refer to this in a static method.

Your `Main` method is static, so it can only access static members. Solution is to change:

`public static int DoStuff(int num1,int num2)`

Answer (score 0):

Either you can stuff the Method with static as show in below or

```
public static  int DoStuff(int num1,int num2)
 {
    int result = num1 + num2;
    return result;
 }
```

**Static methods**:These are called with the type name. No instance is required—this makes them slightly faster. Static methods can be public or private.

**Info:**
Static methods use the static keyword, usually as the first keyword or the second keyword after public.
Warning:
A static method cannot access non-static class level members. It has no "this" pointer.

**Instance:**
An instance method can access those members, but must be called through an instantiated object. This adds indirection.

**For Example**:

```
class Program
   {
    static void MethodA()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Static method");
    }

    void MethodB()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Instance method");
    }

    static char MethodC()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Static method");
        return 'C';
    }

    char MethodD()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Instance method");
        return 'D';
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        //
        // Call the two static methods on the Program type.
        //
        Program.MethodA();
        Console.WriteLine(Program.MethodC());
        //
        // Create a new Program instance and call the two instance methods.
        //
        Program programInstance = new Program();
        programInstance.MethodB();
        Console.WriteLine(programInstance.MethodD());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```